# mpdf memory gets too low when creating bigger pdfs

Tags: php, memory-management, out-of-memory, shared-memory, mpdf

What can I do to prevent running out of memory when working with large (around 11000 records) datasets ?

### The problem

When using [mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) with PHP, I am trying to create PDF files from large datasets (around 11000 records) which is resulting in errors like (memory values fluctuate):

> **Fatal error**: Out of memory (allocated 1197211648) (tried to allocate 44 bytes) in projectfolder\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 24132

### What I tried

It works fine on smaller datasets, and I have tried searcing Stackoverflow articles and other google articles resulting in me making the following changes to my ***php.ini*** file:

```
memory_limit=-1
max_execution_time=0
post_max_size=0
```

### My laptop specifications (where the script is being run) :

- 8GB RAM
- i7 processor
- 64bit OS
- XAMPP

Comment: Adjusted the formatting and language to clarify the intent of the question.  It is generally a good idea to keep the question at the top, following by the problem, and attempts.  Hardware specifications at the bottom is fine, although some more info (can guess some flavor of linux by XAMPP) as to which **64bit OS** is running / versions / etc  if you wish to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

mPDF is, sadly, not optimized to work with large datasets resulting in large HTML.

A thing I would recommend is to create multiple smaller PDF documents if you can and later concatenate them with an external tool such as ghostscript.

Answer (score 0):

Use this after calling the autoload:

```
require_once APPPATH.'libraries/Mpdf/autoload.php';
ini_set("memory_limit","-1");
```